# dataweave array transformation to combine data with same key values

Tags: mule-component, dataweave, mule-esb

I want to combine the list of all projects with the same `companyName` and `companyId`.

I need help processing Data such that it will take all data with the same values for `companyName` and `companyId` and combine it into its own array.

Input Example Data that I expect will be here:

```
[{
    "companyName": "ABC company",
    "companyId": "123",
    "projectName": "project1",
    "levelCode": "893",
    "projectStatus": "2"

},
{
    "companyName": "ABC company",
    "companyId": "123",
    "projectName": "project2",
    "levelCode": "1386",
    "userId": "183",
    "projectStatus": "2"

},
{
    "companyName": "ABC company",
    "companyId": "123",
    "projectName": "project3",
    "levelCode": "1655",
    "userId": "183",
    "projectStatus": "1"

},
{
    "companyName": "ABC company",
    "companyId": "123",
    "projectName": "project4",
    "levelCode": "1865",
    "userId": "159",
    "projectStatus": "2"

}]
```

Expected Output

After Manipulating all the data: Note that all the projects involving `companyName` "ABC company" are now merged into one array (projects).

```
[
  {
    "companyName": "ABC company",
    "companyId": "123",
    "projects": {
      "projectName": "project1",
      "levelCode": "893",
      "projectStatus": "2"
    },
    {
      "projectName": "project2",
      "levelCode": "1386",
      "userId": "183",
      "projectStatus": "2"
    },
    {
      "projectName": "project3",
      "levelCode": "1655",
      "userId": "183",
      "projectStatus": "1"
    },
    {
      "projectName": "project4",
      "levelCode": "1865",
      "userId": "159",
      "projectStatus": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Shu: Typically on Stackoverflow it is expected that you will show what you have already tried. Documentation you have referred to and what you are thinking this process might involve. Also in the future be more careful about your formatting: you can highlight a full snippet of code and then click { } or type ctrl+k [cmd+k].

Answer (score 1):

```
This will work:

%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload distinctBy $.companyName map ((result, IndexOfResult) -> {
    companyName: result.companyName,
    companyId: result.companyId,
    project: payload[?($.companyName == result.companyName)] map {
        projectName: $.projectName,
        levelCode: $.levelCode,
        userId: $.userId,
        projectStatus: $.projectStatus
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this out.

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
payload distinctBy $.CompanyName map {
    companyName: $.companyName,
    companyID: $.companyId,
    Projects: payload map {
        projectName: $.projectName,
        levelCode: $.levelCode,
        userId: $.userId,
        projectStatus: $.projectStatus
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have GroupBy operator with which this can be done easily.
Here you need to group by companyName and companyId 
payload groupBy $.companyName,companyId

Please read the link below for detailed information about groupby operator.
https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/dataweave-operators#group-by